# Is there a way to add a shortcut to eclipse for installing my maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I would like to have a shortcut to maven clean and maven install somewhere in eclipse , is this possible?
[image]

Comment: You can create one under `Run Configuration` and associate a key stroke with it as far as I know...apart from that: Why do you need that inside of Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, hit Ctrl+L twice and bind a shortcut for the _Run Maven Install_ command.

Answer (score 1):

With Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0) on Windows 10, you can open the shortcut list by pressing twice CTL+SHIFT+L.

Then you can search for maven command list by enter maven into the filter box as Eclipse way.

The shortcut you can select is "Run Maven Install"

[image: Eclipse shortcut to Maven Install]

Then you can add a shortcut, as me CTRL+ALT+F12 or something else then choose as "When" > "In Windows" or another context as show below:

[image: Shortcut CTRL+ALT+F12 link to Run Maven Install]

You can test your shortcut after click on "Apply and Close".

Hope that could help someone